Modelling consecutive Poisson point processes, where the second starts only after the first has x counts
I'd like to model a situation where there are 2 consecutive Poisson point processes with different event rates, and the second process only starts after the first process reaches a cumulative event count $x$.
Ultimately, I am interested in knowing the probability of the second process having a cumulative event count $y$ before time $T$, which I reckon equals the probability of having event count $\ge y$ at time $T$.
My current thinking is to:

Express the probability $P(A)$ for the first process to have exactly $x$ events at a variable time $t$, where $0 \le t \le T$.
Then, express the conditional probability $P(B|A)$ for the second process to have $\ge y$ events at time $T$, for which the elapsed time is $T-t$.
Then, the probability $P(B)=P(B|A) \times P(A)$ can be written as a function of $t$
Finally, the probability of interest is the sum of $P(B)$ for all possible $t$, which I can obtain by $\int_{0}^{T} P(B) \,dt$

My questions are:

Am I reinventing the wheel? Is there any established method to model this situation already?
Am I correct, in particular, to define $P(A)$ as the probability of having exactly $x$ events, instead of $\ge x$?
Is there an easier / more elegant alternative to model this situation? Eventually I'd like to model a situation where there are 3 consecutive processes.

Many thanks in advance!

You might like to know that the times to achieve a given number of counts have Gamma distributions.

This is SUPER helpful, thank you so much!!
I just googled and seems like the sum of indepedent gamma distributions is still a gamma distribution.
So essentially I just have to model the waiting time of the two processes, add them together, and find the probability of overall waiting time $\le T$?

That's right.  This is characteristic of the ease of working with Poisson distributions -- they are rather satisfying mathematical objects to study.

@whuber The sum of two independent gamma-distributed random variables with the same rates gives another one (also with the same rate).  But that is not correct here, where the OP says "with different event rates".  In some cases with different rates you can approximate with a suitable gamma distribution, but in others this may not work well.

@Henry That's a good point, because it's really the crux of this question.  As you likely are aware, there are explicit solutions.
